# Generating an array based on min and max number in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I need to generate an array of numbers that has difference of 5000 between them in TypeScript.

So for e.g. the function should be able to take `min` and `max` and based on that it should generate the numbers. So consider the `min` is 0 and `max` is 20000, the array generated should be:

```
[0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000]
```

Comment: Can you please show us your attempted solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first declare an array.
2. Create a method with parameters(minimum and maximum).
3. Call the method with desired parameters.

   ```
     genArray = [];
    generateArray(min, max) {
       let count = min;
       for(count=min; count<=max; count=count+5000) {
       console.log(count);
       this.genArray.push(count);
       }

      generateArray(0,20000);
   ```

Comment: Getting error message at comiple time Operator cannot be applied to number + 500. It referring to the line count= count + 5000. I have declare the parameters  as min: Number, max: Number

Comment: I did this to solve the above but getting error saying that declaraton or statement expected near the private keyword      private generateArray(min: any, max: any) 
   {
    let count = min;
    for(count=min; count<=max; count= count + 5000)
       {
         console.log(count);
         this.genArray.push(count);
       };
   };

Comment: I have finally written as a function but get an error message cannot access genarray  function generateArray(min: any, max: any) 
   {
    let count = min;
    for(count=min; count<=max; count= count + 5000)
       {
         console.log(count);
         this.genArray.push(count);
       };
        
   };

Comment: @Tom, there you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyatm6 and see in the console.